# Google Cloud SQL DeadlineExceededError when we try commit changes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I get exception DeadlineExceededError from my app engine instance at 15:43 (UTC+03).

```
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.
```

In requested method logic like that

```
def post(self):
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    user = User(**data['user'])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return '', 201, {'Location': url_for(request.endpoint)}
```

Google Cloud SQL have incident, but it closed sooner than I got this exception. https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-sql/17010